SwiftUI custom layout disables scroll gestures
I have a custom layout that lays out subviews from left to right, top to bottom. Encapsulating text elements or other subviews within this custom layout then putting it all in a scroll view causes the scroll gestures to be disabled on the nested elements. I tried to add hit testing but that did not work.
Note The subviews within the layout are active and meant to be touched so adding an overlay won't fix the issue.
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            CustomLayoutSec {
                 //can't scroll on this
                Text("Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello")
            }
        }
    }
}

struct CustomLayoutSec: Layout {
    var alignment: Alignment = .leading
    var spacing: CGFloat = 0
    
    func sizeThatFits(proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) -> CGSize {
        let maxWidth = proposal.width ?? 0
        var width: CGFloat = 0
        var height: CGFloat = 0
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)

        for (index, row) in rows.enumerated() {
            var rowWidth = CGFloat.zero
            for (i, subview) in row.enumerated() {
                if i > 0 {
                    rowWidth += spacing
                }
                rowWidth += subview.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
            }
            width = max(width, rowWidth)
            if index == (rows.count - 1) {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal)
            } else {
                height += row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing
            }
        }
        return .init(width: width, height: height)
    }
    
    func placeSubviews(in bounds: CGRect, proposal: ProposedViewSize, subviews: Subviews, cache: inout ()) {
        var origin = bounds.origin
        let maxWidth = bounds.width
        
        let rows = generateRows(maxWidth, proposal, subviews)
        
        for row in rows {
            let leading: CGFloat = bounds.maxX - maxWidth
            let trailing = bounds.maxX - (row.reduce(CGFloat.zero) { partialResult, view in
                let width = view.sizeThatFits(proposal).width
                
                if view == row.last {
                    return partialResult + width
                }
                return partialResult + width + spacing
            })
            let center = (trailing + leading) / 2
            
            origin.x = (alignment == .leading ? leading : alignment == .trailing ? trailing : center)
            
            for view in row {
                let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
                view.place(at: origin, proposal: proposal)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        
            origin.y += (row.maxHeight(proposal) + spacing)
        }
    }
    
    func generateRows(_ maxWidth: CGFloat, _ proposal: ProposedViewSize, _ subviews: Subviews) -> [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] {
        var row: [LayoutSubviews.Element] = []
        var rows: [[LayoutSubviews.Element]] = []
        
        var origin = CGRect.zero.origin
        
        for view in subviews {
            let viewSize = view.sizeThatFits(proposal)
            
            if (origin.x + viewSize.width + spacing) > maxWidth {
                rows.append(row)
                row.removeAll()
                origin.x = 0
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            } else {
                row.append(view)
                origin.x += (viewSize.width + spacing)
            }
        }

        if !row.isEmpty {
            rows.append(row)
            row.removeAll()
        }
        
        return rows
    }
}

extension [LayoutSubviews.Element] {
    func maxHeight(_ proposal: ProposedViewSize) -> CGFloat {
        return self.compactMap { view in
            return view.sizeThatFits(proposal).height
        }.max() ?? 0
    }
}


Try this approach using a ScrollView(.horizontal) and some height for the CustomLayoutSec,
for example:
struct SomeView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){  // <--- here
            CustomLayoutSec {
                Text("Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello Hello")
            }
            .frame(height: 55) // <--- here
        }
    }
}


Thanks, the height is not static how would I decide the height if the embedded views can be any size? Also Im working with a basic vertical scroll view.

I put the frame just for the scroll bar, you can remove it if you want and the view will adjust.
You can use .padding(20) to give a bit of space for the scroll bar.
